# Binary To String Conversion

Tags: python, string, binary, typeerror

I'm relatively new to python and I'm trying to design a program that takes an input of Binary Data and Converts it to a String of Text. I have the following so far but keep getting the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'` Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? And, if so, advise how to fix it?

```
a = int(input("please enter the binary you want to convert: "))

for str in a:
    g = [~(chr(str)&~240)|(e&~240)]
    f = 86
    e = 231
    d = bin(chr(str))
    b = (str)

j=(b)

print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot wrong with what you're doing; I'm not sure how you get the error you claim to have, given the other errors in the posted code. In order of reading the function:

1. Don't call your own variables `str`, it prevents you from accessing the built-in of the same name. Also, that variable either isn't a `str`, or causes a `TypeError` on `chr(str)`.
2. You can't iterate over an integer `for x in y:`; this is also a `TypeError`.
3. *(The error you report)* `chr(str)` returns a string of length one. This is not a valid operand type for `&`, hence `TypeError`.
4. Another operand, `e`, has not yet been defined, so that will be a `NameError`.
5. Irrespective of that, you never use `g` again anyway.
6. Or `f` - what's that even for?
7. Now `e` *is* defined!
8. `bin(chr(str))` will never work - again, `chr` returns a string, and `bin` takes a number as an argument.
9. `b = (str)` works, but the parentheses are redundant.
10. Same with `j = (b)`, which is also not indented far enough to be in the loop.
11. Neither is `print(j)`.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, exactly. If you gave example inputs (what format is the "Binary Data"?) and outputs (and what "String of Text" do you want to get?) along with your actual code and the full error traceback this might be easier.

---

#### Edit

With the information provided in your comment, it appears that you are trying to reverse these operations:

```
a = input("please enter the text you want to hide: ")
for ch in a:
##    b = (ch) # this still doesn't do anything!
    c = ord(ch)
##    d = bin(c) # and d is never used
##    e = 231 # e is only used to calculate g
    f = 86
##    g = (((c&240) >> 4)|(e&240)) # which is also never used
    h = (((c&15)|(f&240)))
    j = bin(h)
    print(j)
```

This produces, for example (`a == 'foo'`):

```
0b1010110
0b1011111
0b1011111
```

However, to convert the input `'0b1010110'` to an integer, you need to supply `int` with the appropriate base:

```
>>> int('0b1010110', 2)
86
```

and you can't iterate over the integer. I think you want something like:

```
data = input("please enter the binary you want to convert: ")
for j in data.split():
    h = int(j, 2)
    ...
```

where the input would be e.g. `'0b1010110 0b1011111 0b1011111'`, or just do one at a time:

```
h = int(input(...), 2)
```

Note that, as the function is reversed, you will have to define `f` *before* trying to go back through the bitwise operation.

Comment: the first part of the program was not designed by myself but they converted a string of text to binary using the following program:

import string

a = input("please enter the text you want to hide: ")

for ch in a:
    b = (ch)
    c = ord(ch)
    d = bin (c)
    e = 231
    f = 86
    g = (((c&240) >> 4)|(e&240))
    h = (((c&15)|(f&240)))

    j=bin(h)


    print(j)

at the moment im just trying to get it to convert from binary to a string of text before editing it to convert the result of that program back to a string of text. i do realize this makes no sense what so ever in this comment.

Comment: @user3569226 and how is that at all related to what *you* are trying to do? Please update your question with more information. You have introduced many errors in your attempt to modify that code.

Comment: @user3569226 I have updated my answer based on your comment. You should have included all of that information in the original question.